# Кластеризация акций на основе МСФО отчетности

Tags: машинное-обучение, кластеризация, feature-engineering

Всем привет. Я хочу провести кластеризацию акций на основе  характеристик из квартальных МСФО отчетов компаний.

Я собрал квартальные отчеты за период с 2018 по 2022 год. У некоторых компаний есть отчеты за все кварталы всех лет, некоторые публикуют отчеты два раза в год..

Итак, перед предварительной обработкой данных и самой кластеризацией мне нужно понять, как будут выглядеть мои данные. Это и есть мой вопрос. У меня есть данные за период с 2018 по 2022 год, и мне, на мой взгляд, нужно их агрегировать, чтобы описать то, что происходило с 2018 по 2022 год. Какие у меня есть варианты? Если я просто найду только средние значения каждого признака для каждой компании, я потеряю много информации.

Варианты, которые я придумал:

1. Сгруппировать данные по годам и рассматривать каждый год отдельно
2. Обобщить данные по каждой компании, но вычислить не только среднее значение, но и медиану, стандартное отклонение, максимальное/минимальное значение и так далее.

Заранее спасибо за советы!

Comment: Вам скорее всего никто готового ответа не скажет. Подход именно такой и должен быть: сначала напридумывать много разных фич, а потом смотреть, какие из них реально оказались полезными.